# FactoryGirl undefined method `create='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm basically getting an error when I'm trying to use a factory I created for a Post model in Ruby on Rails.

Here's the full error:

```
 Failure/Error: post = create(:post)

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `create=' for #<Post:0x007fbf1be6e510>
   Did you mean?  created_at=
 # ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's the file for the factories:

`spec/factories/post.rb`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :post do
        title "Hello"
        content "Hello, my name is Jacob."
        user create(:user)
        user_id 1
    end
end
```

`spec/models/post_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

describe Post do
    it "has a valid factory" do
        post = create(:post)
        expect(post).to(be_valid)
    end
end
```

I do have a `spec/support/factory_girl.rb` file which includes the FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods. This file is loaded by `spec/rails_helper.rb`.

Also, the create(:user) line works and I'm able to use the user factory in the rails console, but not the post factory.

Any help would be fantastic. Thank you!

Comment: A few comments ... does your `rails_helper.rb` not already require `spec_helper` for you? Also, instead of `post = create(:post)` it is typical to use `let(:post) { create :post }` outside of your `it` statement, particularly if you are going to perform many tests against that post object.

Comment: You're right. It does already require `spec_helper`. And thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `post` factory, you have the syntax wrong for defining an associated record. Try defining it like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    title "Hello"
    content "Hello, my name is Jacob."
    user
  end
end
```

You just need to state that the `post` has a `user`, and you certainly shouldn't be setting them all to have a specific `user_id` ... since each post will create a new user unless told otherwise and you have no idea what `user_id` will be generated.